# laravel "Undefined variable: categories "

Tags: laravel

I am trying to display my categories in the welcome.blade.php, however it gives me an error.

My welcome.blade.php:

```
<div class="links">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <a href="{{ url('/receitas/'.$category->id)}}">{{ $category->name }}</a>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

My WelcomeController.php:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use App\Category;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Welcome;

class WelcomeController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }

    public function show()
    {
    $categories = Category::all();

    return view('welcome', compact([ 'categories' => $categories]));
    }
}
```

And my web.php:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index')->name('entrada');

Route::get('/teste/teste', 'UserController@index');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/receitas', 'ReceitasController@index')->name('receitas');

Route::get('/clientes', 'HomeController@clientes');

Route::get('/category', 'CategoryController@index');
```

I have already tried to use a @if condition to verify if the variable $categories is empty and it seem it is.

```
<div class="links">
                @if(empty($categories))
                    Alert: the variable is empty!!
                @else
                    @foreach($categories as $category)
                        <a href="{{ url('/receitas/'.$category->id)}}">{{ $category->name }}</a>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            </div>
```

However in my database I have records of categories.

[Printscreen of my category table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diQuT.png)

Can you help me please!

Comment: Can you report the error message?

Comment: do something like this `return view('welcome', ['categories' =>$categories]);
`

Comment: @Webinion I tried your suggestion, but it returns the same error...

Comment: @DanieleD. the error message is: "Undefined variable: categories (View: /Sites/laravel/laravel-intro/resources/‌​views/welcome.blade.‌​php)"

Comment: use only  `compact('categories')` in WelcomeController or use `view('welcome')->with('categories', $categories);`

Comment: @JigneshSolanki I had already tried that, but still not working...

I tried all these options:
`return view('welcome', compact([ 'categories' => $categories]));
    //return view('welcome', compact('categories'));
    //return view('/')->withCategories($categories);
    //return view('welcome', $categories);
    //return View::make('welcome')->with('categories', $categories);`

Comment: @ribeiro.csa are you sure you are invoking correct method? you have 2 methods `index()` and `show()`. you have to call `show()` instead of `index()`.

Comment: @JigneshSolanki I am using index() now and it's working!